# Will an app developed for S60 3rd edition, work on Symbian belle?

Tags: java-me, symbian, qt-mobility, symbian3

I want to develop app for Symbian Devices. Can an app developed for S60 3rd edition and 5th edition work on Symbian Anna and Belle.

How to develop an app for supporting as much as possible and newer device?.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, App developed for 3rd edition will work on Anna and Belle